# Create and set the bibliography

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to know which package and style would you suggest in order to create the bibliography.

I need a bibliography in alphabetic order, that I can edit. I mean, I want the title of the section as "REFERENCES" in Times New Roman 12pt instead of "References" - which is an automatic heading.
The bibliography itself has to be in Times New Roman 11pt.

Thank you for your attention.

Nicolo'

p.s.
this is what I am using, but I don't know how to change font, sizes etc.
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliography{biblio} 
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: They two suggestions don't work unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Would like this to be a comment rather than a full on answer, but you can change the bibliography title with

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textsc{References}}
```

Or if you're using babel:

```
\addto\captions<yourLanguage>{%
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\textsc{References}}%
}
```

As for the font part, if you haven't done anything crazy thus far (which I assume given your question), the easiest would be to stick with your document font which should be some kind of 10-12 pts computer super, which is (as you must've noticed) a classical serif font, not too far apart from TNR.

[image]